# Wordpress intallation in localhost CPanel software/app

Tags: wordpress, installation, localhost, cpanel

is there any localhost CPanel like app/software that we can install wordpress?
because I would like to teach on how to install wordpress in CPanel just using localhost setup so we can avoid damaging our host CPanel.

Many thanks :)

Comment: login to your Cpanel  see screenshot http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ec6108bfc

Answer (score 0):

You can install WordPress in any subdomain or sub directory on your website to avoid any main host damage. As a result, you do not need to setup any local environment for testing purpose.

Nowadays, most of the hosting providers offer one click installation tool [like Fantastico, Softaculous etc..,] in cPanel from where you can install WordPress in a minute.